# Alternative to Iframe (same domain)

Tags: html, iframe

I wonder if there is a working way (compliant with most browsers) to show other pages inside a page which belongs to the same domain - I just learned IFRAMES do not allow this- they can only be used to show the content from external sites - right?

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *- they can only be used to show the content from external sites - right?*

**No.** There is no restriction on the `src` attribute of [`<iframe>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element)s (*living standard - HTML 4*).

---

If you're not particularly fond of how the current HTML standard offers information, have a look at MDN's page on  [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)s - some find its format friendlier.

The main difference between `<iframe>` and any alternative is that the `<iframe>` acts like an independent page (it doesn't share resources with its parent document), while **fragment / component / template** loading is about creating placeholders in a document where contents from another file on the same server will be placed at parse time (so all scripts/styles in parent will apply to the fragment and any such resources loaded by fragment will also affect the parent).

Fragments / components / templates are now only possible through the use of libraries (most popular being jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) but will probably be possible as part of `HTML` once [`HTML Components`](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLComponents) will become *living standard*.

While some might feel I should have mentioned [`Shadow DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) here, it is only a special case of `HTML Components`, which encapsulates its styles and scripts so they do not apply outside the component and also provides a few handy methods to do it (`:host`, `:host()` and `:host-context()`).
Currently, `Shadow DOM` is a working draft and using it cross browser is only possible with [`webcomponents.js`](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs).

Comment: Thank you for your kind and very detailed reply. I have been reading on multiple sites that iframes cannot show same domain pages - this is not true? for example - http://www.bielousov.com/2012/iframe-same-origin-script-policy/

Comment: On the contrary. [`Same origin policy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restricts resources from being loaded when they have a different origin than the parent document and requires additional scripting/permissions when the origins differ. In effect, the child needs to specify the parents that are allowed to load it. If the current parent matches the rules, the request is allowed and the child is displayed.

Comment: sweet - thnak you very much for taking the time to explain this to me!)